# Error when I compile ffmpeg in Xcode5

Tags: ios, ffmpeg

I compile ffmpeg in OSX. My xcode version is 5.1. ffmpeg configure is :

```
./configure --disable-doc --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --enable-cross-compile --arch=arm --target-os=darwin --cc=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc  --as='gas-preprocessor/gas-preprocessor.pl /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc  ' --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk --cpu=cortex-a8 --extra-cflags='-arch armv7' --extra-ldflags='-arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk' --enable-pic --disable-asm --prefix="../lib"
```

This is the error:

```
/usr/bin/ranlib: object: libavfilter/libavfilter.a(aeval.o) malformed object (unknown load command 1)
ar: internal ranlib command failed
make: *** [libavfilter/libavfilter.a] Error 1
```

I'm not sure what this error means or how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are trying to build it for ARM, therefore iOS...

It's not that simple... run this script here... if you uncomment X264 you can compile it with libx264, if you need that, I can send you the other script later.

```
#!/bin/sh

# directories
SOURCE="ffmpeg-2.3"
FAT=`pwd`/"fat"

SCRATCH="scratch"
# must be an absolute path
THIN=`pwd`/"thin"

# absolute path to x264 library
#X264=`pwd`/../x264/fat

CONFIGURE_FLAGS="--enable-cross-compile \
                --disable-debug \
                --disable-programs \
                --disable-doc \
                --enable-pic \
                --enable-cross-compile \
                --target-os=darwin \
                --enable-nonfree \
                --enable-gpl \
                --enable-static \
                --disable-shared \
                --disable-armv5te \
                --disable-swscale-alpha \
                --disable-doc \
                --disable-ffmpeg \
                --disable-ffplay \
                --disable-ffprobe \
                --disable-ffserver \
                --disable-asm"

if [ "$X264" ]
then
    CONFIGURE_FLAGS="$CONFIGURE_FLAGS --enable-gpl --enable-libx264"
fi

# avresample
#CONFIGURE_FLAGS="$CONFIGURE_FLAGS --enable-avresample"

ARCHS="arm64 armv7s armv7 x86_64 i386"

COMPILE="y"
LIPO="y"

DEPLOYMENT_TARGET="6.0"

if [ "$*" ]
then
    if [ "$*" = "lipo" ]
    then
        # skip compile
        COMPILE=
    else
        ARCHS="$*"
        if [ $# -eq 1 ]
        then
            # skip lipo
            LIPO=
        fi
    fi
fi

if [ "$COMPILE" ]
then
    if [ ! `which yasm` ]
    then
        echo 'Yasm not found'
        if [ ! `which brew` ]
        then
            echo 'Homebrew not found. Trying to install...'
            ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)" \
                || exit 1
        fi
        echo 'Trying to install Yasm...'
        brew install yasm || exit 1
    fi
    if [ ! `which gas-preprocessor.pl` ]
    then
        echo 'gas-preprocessor.pl not found. Trying to install...'
        (curl -3L https://github.com/libav/gas-preprocessor/raw/master/gas-preprocessor.pl \
            -o /usr/local/bin/gas-preprocessor.pl \
            && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gas-preprocessor.pl) \
            || exit 1
    fi

    if [ ! -r $SOURCE ]
    then
        echo 'FFmpeg source not found. Trying to download...'
        curl http://www.ffmpeg.org/releases/$SOURCE.tar.bz2 | tar xj \
            || exit 1
    fi

    CWD=`pwd`
    for ARCH in $ARCHS
    do
        echo "building $ARCH..."
        mkdir -p "$SCRATCH/$ARCH"
        cd "$SCRATCH/$ARCH"

        CFLAGS="-arch $ARCH"
        if [ "$ARCH" = "i386" -o "$ARCH" = "x86_64" ]
        then
            PLATFORM="iPhoneSimulator"
            CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -mios-simulator-version-min=$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"
        else
            PLATFORM="iPhoneOS"
            CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -mios-version-min=$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"
            if [ "$ARCH" = "arm64" ]
            then
                EXPORT="GASPP_FIX_XCODE5=1"
            fi
        fi

        XCRUN_SDK=`echo $PLATFORM | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`
        CC="xcrun -sdk $XCRUN_SDK clang"
        CXXFLAGS="$CFLAGS"
        LDFLAGS="$CFLAGS"
        if [ "$X264" ]
        then
            CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -I$X264/include"
            LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -L$X264/lib"
        fi

        $CWD/$SOURCE/configure \
            --target-os=darwin \
            --arch=$ARCH \
            --cc="$CC" \
            $CONFIGURE_FLAGS \
            --extra-cflags="$CFLAGS" \
            --extra-cxxflags="$CXXFLAGS" \
            --extra-ldflags="$LDFLAGS" \
            --prefix="$THIN/$ARCH" \
        || exit 1

        make -j3 install $EXPORT || exit 1
        cd $CWD
    done
fi

if [ "$LIPO" ]
then
    echo "building fat binaries..."
    mkdir -p $FAT/lib
    set - $ARCHS
    CWD=`pwd`
    cd $THIN/$1/lib
    for LIB in *.a
    do
        cd $CWD
        echo lipo -create `find $THIN -name $LIB` -output $FAT/lib/$LIB 1>&2
        lipo -create `find $THIN -name $LIB` -output $FAT/lib/$LIB || exit 1
    done

    cd $CWD
    cp -rf $THIN/$1/include $FAT
fi

echo Done
```

Comment: thanks for you help.but when i run you script,there is a error:INSTALL libavdevice/libavdevice.a
ranlib: object: /Users/leepengfei/Desktop/ffmpeg/thin/arm64/lib/libavdevice.a(alldevices.o) malformed object (unknown load command 1)
make: *** [install-libavdevice-static] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs.... please help me

Comment: it looks like you corrupted your toolchain someway... try this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125915/arm64-build-error-during-building-libetpan-project